# Bertrand's ballots puzzle - Proof by reflection

Tags: probability

I am looking for a some clarification to the proof of the Bertrand's ballot [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_ballot_theorem#Proof_by_reflection).

I understood the the trick with swapping B(A) for A(B) in every position up to the first tie.

**What I don't quite get is why the probability of beginning a sequence with B expressed as $\frac{b}{a+b}$  represents the probability of getting at least one tie when starting with B.**

It seems those are two different things. Secondly how does it account for many combinations giving the sequencies with a tie.

Can anybody explain this link please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument given at your link shows that there is a bijection between sequences that reach a tie at some point and sequences that begin with $B$. Thus, there are exactly as many sequences that reach a tie at some point as there are sequences that begin with $B$. Let $n$ be the number of sequences that reach a tie at some point (and hence also the number that begin with $B$). There are $\binom{a+b}a$ sequences altogether, since a sequence is completely determined once you know the $a$ positions of the $A$s, so the probability that a randomly chosen sequence reaches a tie at some point is $\frac{n}{\binom{a+b}a}$, and this is also the probability that a randomly chosen sequence begins with $B$. But we can directly evaluate that probability as $\frac{b}{a+b}$, since each sequence has $b$ $B$s and $a$ $A$s. Thus

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Pr}(\text{there is a tie at some point})&=\frac{n}{\binom{a+b}a}\\
&=\operatorname{Pr}(\text{sequence starts with }B)\\
&=\frac{b}{a+b}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

The key point in answer to your specific question is:

- The probability that a vote counting sequence starts with a vote for B is exactly the probability that the first vote counted is for candidate B, which is $\dfrac{b}{a+b}$.

The related points are

- $a \gt b$ so eventually Candidate A must win
- So any vote counting sequence which starts with a vote for B must have at least one tie point, since candidate B starts ahead but candidate A wins in the end
- The reflection between the start and the first tie, leading to a bijection between ties where the first vote is for B and ties where the first vote is for A, means that the probability of a tie at some stage is therefore $2\dfrac{b}{a+b}$
- The probability candidate A is always ahead in the count is the probability there are no ties at any stage, which is then $1-2\dfrac{b}{a+b}=\dfrac{a-b}{a+b}$